# Need a counter class name

Tags: java, class, counter

I'm writing a counter class which doesn't have a nice name yet. It counts occurence of numbers within a defined range such as [0-10), [10-100). How can I call this counter? Is `StagedCounter` OK? My English vocabulary is very poor.

Comment: You just need a name to it???

Comment: what kind of question is this omg .. april fool

Comment: Yes, Is it allowed to ask for naming in stackoverflow.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `IntervalCounter` would be better because you are counting your data in intervals.

Answer (score 0):

just `Counter` is fine. Next time you have a naming issue, just let it rest for a day or so and you'll come up with a better answer. I also suggest looking at [java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Edit : Dhwaneet's proposal `IntervalCounter` is indeed better.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/CodeConventions.pdf

Except for variables, all instance, class, and
class constants are in mixed case with a lowercase
first letter. Internal words start with capital
letters.
Variable names should be short yet meaningful.
The choice of a variable name should be
mnemonic— that is, designed to indicate to the
casual observer the intent of its use.

Therefore, definately your variable should start with a lower letter, and secondly the name is up to you. If that helps you understand what this variable is used for, then go ahead and use it.

I agree with the other two opinions that **intervalCounter**  maybe better